# Spring - Is it possible to have an external configuration project NOT as a running service but, as a dependency?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have several spring service projects that are all running on separate servers but, share many of the same configuration files and initialized beans. To reduce redundancy, I would like to have a separate project that can provide most of the spring configuration and beans. Ideally, the project would NOT be a @SpringBootApplication and instead be some type of serverless project that has snapshots & releases instead. That way, I can just pull that entire project as a separate dependency like

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>my-group</groupId>
  <artifactId>external-config-project</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I have heard of Spring Cloud Config & Spring Cloud Function but, I am confused on how to use them or if this is even what I am looking for? In the [docs](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-config), they have this code block:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RestController
public class Application {

  @Value("${config.name}")
  String name = "World";

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String home() {
    return "Hello " + name;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

}
```

While it might not be a "Spring Application" it still appears to me as a separate running application ?

EDIT: I already have a separate software to handle release/snapshot uploads but, not sure how it would work with this style project.

Answer (score 0):

you can just package your shared spring config module as jar and import in your services. add the package name of the shared module in the scan packages annotation of your services so that spring will scan them.

Spring cloud config is a server. dont think it is what you are after